# Pass a dynamic parameter in reactive form custom validator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

I would like to pass a variable as a parameter in a custom validator like this

```
    newSimulation: new FormControl('', [uniqNameValidator(this.options)])
```

Then use it in my custom validator

```
export function uniqNameValidator(list: any): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const simulationFlatList = list.map(val => val.closingPeriodSimulationName)
    return simulationFlatList.indexOf(control.value) > -1 ? { message: "simulation exists" } : null;
  }
}
```

The issue with this is that `this.options` is always empty. I initialize it to `[]` but when user interacts with the form ( first field ) I update it to an array of string, I think that the custom validator does not recheck the value of `this.options` ?
In this case how to pass a variable in custom validator ?

Comment: have you tried     ```newSimulation: new FormControl('', [uniqNameValidator(this.options)])``` it looks to me like you are passing a callback that returns this.options to your validator as the argument

Comment: I have updated my answer , actually it was like you mentioned but still not working too

Comment: I confirm the custom validator only takes the initial value of options :/

Comment: Its been a minute since I worked with validators, I believe the form control passes `control` (DynamicFormControlModel or AbstractControl) as the first value, instead of passing in `this.options`, you can put the validator function in your component and access the options with `this`

Comment: @infodev have you found a solution to this problem? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

this may work, bind the function to component `newSimulation: new FormControl('', [uniqNameValidator.bind(this)])` then in the function you can access `this.options`